# Any way to query inheritance base type in breeze, but get the concrete properties

Tags: breeze

Assuming an object model like the following:

```
abstract BaseObject  
{  
    Id { get;set; }  
}

ObjectTypeA : BaseObject
{  
    SomeProperty { get;set; }  
}

ObjectTypeB : BaseObject
{  
    AnotherProperty { get;set; }  
}
```

If I do a query against an `IQueryable<BaseObject>` I will get instances of both inherited types in my collection, but I cannot access SomeProperty or AnotherProperty, although the entityAspect data does have the correct type information for both of the subtypes.

It does make a sense in a certain regard as the query is asking for a specific type of object back, which is what I'm getting.  However on the client side I would be able to cast the objects and access the properties.

Is there a workaround that would allow a similar behaviour in breeze?

The alternative I see is properly having to do two queries in breeze for each of the inherited types, and then somehow combining the results and working with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. You queried for the base type (a so-called polymorphic query) and received concrete entities in return. Each of these entities has its own properties as well as those of the base type. You can reference those properties in your client app just fine.

In your example, I can only query the base type by `Id` which means I will receive a single entity on the client, either an 'A' or a 'B'. You can ask the object if it is an 'A' or 'B'. Because you're in JavaScript you don't need to cast. You can tell if an object has the `someProperty` or the `anotherProperty` simply by asking for it. The whole notion of "casting" is kind of irrelevant in JavaScript. Maybe I just don't understand your point.

A more wide-ranging polymorphic query could populate the Breeze EntityManager cache with 'A' and 'B' types. You can follow that up with another query ... a cache only query that won't go to the server ... that targets the 'A' or 'B' types specifically ... if you want to filter by a type's property after a mix of entities have been loaded in cache. Maybe that is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  Essentially I wasn't sure if you could do 'polymorphic' queries like this with breeze.  I wasn't getting the 'someproperty' and 'anotherproperty' properties on my specific instances, although I was getting the different types back in the query.  I thought this was breeze somehow kind of mapping the entities to the lowest common denominator, but it turned out to be more about how my modal was organised than breeze's behaviour.  So your answer, although not specifically fixing my problem, did point out it was my problem, not breeze's!!  Thanks!